# NSInvalidArgumentException when reloading UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my `UIViewController`:

```
class HabitTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var habitTableView: UITableView!
    private var _numOfRowsInSects: [Int] = []
    private var _habitsByDaySet = false
    private var _habitsBySection:[[Habit]] = []
    private var _whatIsToday = -1 


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        habitTableView.delegate = self
        habitTableView.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func reloadTableForDay(sender: DayButton){
        if sender.tag != getDayOfWeek(-1){
            _whatIsToday = sender.tag
            self.habitTableView.reloadData() //line of exception
        }
        else{
            _whatIsToday = -1
        }

    }
    // methods of UITableView delegate and data source implemented 

}
```

I got an `NSInvalidArgumentException` at the line `self.habitTableView.reloadData()`, and the reason is `-[HabitWiz.HabitTableViewController reloadTableForDay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb0d351b060`. I have no idea what is going on here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint before that line, and checking the pointer to the habitTableView. This looks like the tableView might be getting deallocated before realoading the data.

Comment: the problem is it breaks before i click the button and i can't find `instance 0x7fb033c1a310`

Comment: Have you checked if you have implemented all necessary delegate methods then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I realized my app wasn't building correctly: I inserted a couple of `print` statements which weren't executed. So I just did a clean build, and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you messed up with the IBAction in the interface builder.

Try to unwire and re-wire the action and be sure the ViewController is set to be a subclass of HabitTableViewController.

Comment: that's not it, I double checked